# How does this instantiation of this class works?

Tags: java

I used to create instance of class like this;

```
Classname a=new Classname();

OR

Classname a=new Classname(1,2,3);
```

But below coding is being quite confusing.
 Why do they enclosed with bracket and including method inside.
 wht do we putting semicolon at end?

```
LocationResult locationResult = new LocationResult(){
    @Override
    public void gotLocation(Location location){

    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an [anonymous class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html). It is a combination of a class definition and class instantiation: it lets you define a class (extending another class or interface) *without giving it a name* and instantiate it at the same place. This is useful when you're only going to use this particular class in *one* place in your code: you don't really want to give it a name as you won't use to it anywhere else. For example, when binding an click event listener to a particular GUI button, you probably won't use that same click event listener class for any other button.

In the end, this is all just syntactic sugar. You can achieve the same thing by defining a named class elsewhere and instantiating it as usual. Anonymous classes may help you to make your code more concise by putting the definition of a class which you'll only use once at the same place where you're using it.

As for the syntax: think of it like regular class instantiation, but with the class definition added in between. You start off with:

```
LocationResult locationResult = new LocationResult();
```

(Of course this probably won't work, as `LocationResult` is most likely an interface or an abstract class and thus you can't instantiate it like that.)

Then, you simply add the class definition between the `)` and the `;`

```
LocationResult locationResult = new LocationResult(){
    @Override
    public void gotLocation(Location location){

    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

It's an anonymous override. It's often used when you want to create an anonymous action listener that is specific to a certain component. Instead of creating a separate class that's able to be referenced by multiple components, you can create an anonymous class that is only used once.

From the [Java tutorials on anonymous classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html): "Anonymous classes enable you to make your code more concise. They enable you to declare and instantiate a class at the same time. They are like local classes except that they do not have a name. Use them if you need to use a local class only once."

For example, the below creates an anonymous ActionListener class specifically for a JButton.

```
JButton button = new JButton();

button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //do something specific to this button
        //this is an anonymous ActionListener class
    }
});
```